# How to disable dropdown list when maximum limit of hours is reached?

Tags: excel

I would like to ask some help on how to disable the dropdown list that I created in excel that has Yes and No when the total hours is reached the maximum limit hours of 50? also this is need to have warning error validation that will stop them from adding more numbers Example is "hours should not be more than 50". Hope you can help me. Thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpRGl.png)

Comment: Put an if() around each value in the list that if a condition is met or not met then blank, or a message “hours > 50”.

Comment: Hi @SolarMike, Thank you for your time answering my question. I have already scripts for the limit of hours validation (see below), what I am missing is the scripts on how to disable the dropdown list that has Yes and No when the total hours reached the limit hours example the limit is 50hrs. Do you have any idea on how I can do that or it is not possible?

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
 
    If Range("D63") > 51 Then
           MsgBox "Hours should be not more than 50", vbCritical, "Hours Exceeded"
        End If
    If Range("E63") > 71 Then
           MsgBox "Hours should be not more than 70", vbCritical, "Hours Exceeded"
        End If
    If Range("F63") > 91 Then
           MsgBox "Hours should be not more than 90", vbCritical, "Hours Exceeded"
        End If